# Creating a variable to a directory that persists until deletion

Tags: bash

I'm currently using bash on Ubuntu, and I work a lot with a directory saved at /home/me/path/to/project_dir. It is a nuisance to change to the directory every time I open bash. So I'd like to save the path to a variable, say `projdir`, so that I can just do `cd projdir`. If my working directory changes, I should be able to change the path by overwriting the variable. I want to be able to update the variable easily, preferably with one command, without messing with .bashrc.

One important thing is that this variable should persist even if I restart bash. How do I do this? I'd still like to see my home directory when I start up bash, so changing the default starting directory to project_dir is not an option.

Comment: What's your terminal emulator?

Comment: What is wrong with `.bashrc`? That is designed for these things!

Comment: @Bernhard, Sorry for getting back to you all really late. I was busy with other things. I'm not really an experienced Linux user, so I wanted to avoid messing with .bashrc. But, I understand that it is designed for these things, so I should probably get used to it.

Comment: @CookieMonster Yep, you should use `.bashrc` to your advantage, I am sure you will like it once you get use to it! Try to read up on aliases and functions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at CDPATH in `man bash` maybe that is already enough.

Otherwise define some alias in .bashrc. I would suggest:

```
alias setp='pwd >~/.projectdir'
alias gop='cd $(cat ~/.projectdir)'
```

Comment: I think I will go with this approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'PROJDIR="/home/me/path/to/project_dir"' > ~/.projdir
# put the next in e.g. .bashrc
projdir () {
  . ~/.projdir
  cd "$PROJDIR"
}
# change into directory simply by
projdir
# if dir changes just repeat
echo 'PROJDIR="/home/me/path/to/other_project_dir"' > ~/.projdir
# and instantly this works from all shells / consoles:
projdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a symbolic link in your home directory.

```
ln -s path/to/project_dir ~/p
```

Run `cd p` to switch to that project directory.

That's a bit of a cumbersome approach though. You could run one shell and switch to the desired directories, then start other shells from it, by running `xterm & disown` (replace `xterm` by whatever terminal emulator you prefer).